# Make onMomentumScrollEnd listen to only touch interactions - not scrollTo method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` and I am using the `onMomentumScrollEnd` event to trigger a function but I also have a button that uses the scrollTo method which then also fires the function from the `onMomentumScrollEnd` event. Is there way to trigger the `onMomentumScrollEnd` event only when it is from a touch interaction?

I have tried to use `onScrollEndDrag` instead since it is specific to touch interactions, but I specifically need the position of the `ScrollView` when it glides to a stop